# Drawing a Drawable to a Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable

I have an XML drawable file with a stroke, and I also have several bitmaps which I want to apply the stroke to.  I tried calling Drawable.draw(canvas), but it throws IllegalStateException

stroke XML:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke android:width="3dp"
            android:color="#ffffffff"/>
</shape>
```

Drawing code:

```
Drawable strokeDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.stroke);
Bitmap bmp1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bmp1);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp1);
strokeDrawable.draw(canvas);
```

How should I do this?

Comment: Can you show the full LogCat please?

Comment: Silly me. Upon closer reading from the logcat, it's because the bitmap is immutable. I just added `bmp1.copy()`, and it doesn't throw the exception anymore, though the stroke is not visible (probably drawn out of the bounds of the bitmap).

Comment: You may try the [`<padding ...>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) technique. If that fails, you may have to resize the `Bitmap` by hand according to the size of the canvas.

Comment: Turns out padding isn't necessary. I need to call `strokeDrawable.setBounds(0,0,bmp1.getWidth(),bmp1.getHeight())` before `draw`. Will post the overall solution as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution:

```
final int STROKE_WIDTH = 3;
Bitmap copy = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.getWidth() + STROKE_WIDTH * 2, bmp1.getHeight() + STROKE_WIDTH * 2, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(copy);
strokeDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, copy.getWidth(), copy.getHeight());
strokeDrawable.draw(canvas);
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, STROKE_WIDTH, STROKE_WIDTH, null);
bmp1.recycle();
bmp1 = copy;
```